# Sorting a subclass in Java

Tags: java, sorting, inheritance

Suppose a `Superclass implements Comparable<Superclass>`, such that `Arrays.sort(ArrayOfSuperInstances);` uses this `compareTo(Superclass other)` method to sort. Does this guarantee that an array of instances of `Subclass extends Superclass` will sort in the same way using `Arrays.sort(ArrayOfSubInstances);` ? (Assuming the compareTo is not overloaded in the subclass definition)

Or in other words, will `Subclass` by default inherit the `compareTo` method of its `Superclass` , so that one can blindly use `Arrays.sort()` knowing they will be sorted as superclasses would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- that is the whole principle behind polymporphism, and specifically the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, if A is a subclass of B, then you should be able to use A anywhere you'd be able to use B, and it should essentially act the same as any other instance of B (or other subclasses of B).

So, not only will it happen, but it's almost always what you want to happen. It's usually wrong to `compareTo` in the subclass.

Why? Well, part of the `Comparable<T>` contract is that comparison is transitive. Since your superclass will presumably not know what its subclasses are doing, if a subclass overrides `compareTo` in such a way that it gives an answer different than its superclass, it breaks the contract.

So for instance, let's say you have something like a Square and a ColorSquare. Square's `compareTo` compares the two squares' sizes:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Square other) {
    return this.len - other.len;
}
```

...while ColorSquare also adds a comparison for color (let's assume colors are Comparable). Java won't let you have ColorSquare implement `Comparable<ColorSquare>` (since its superclass already implements `Comparable<Square>`), but you can use reflection to get around this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Square other) {
    int cmp = super.compareTo(other);
    // don't do this!
    if (cmp == 0 && (other instanceof ColorSquare)) {
        ColorSquare otherColor = (ColorSquare) other;
        cmp = color.compareTo(otherColor.color);
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

This looks innocent enough at first. If both shapes are ColorSquare, they'll compare on length and color; otherwise, they'll only compare on length.

But what if you have:

```
Square a = ...
ColorSquare b = ...
ColorSquare c = ...

assert a.compareTo(b) == 0;  // assume this and the other asserts succeed
assert a.compareTo(c) == 0;
// transitivity implies that b.compareTo(c) is also 0, but maybe
// they have the same lengths but different color!
assert b.compareTo(c) == 1; // contract is broken!
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, I understood this Liskov substitution principle (although I didn't know this term), but I felt uneasy because of the special role of comparables in Java... (i.e. I felt uncertain that the subclasses were still comparable as superclasses, and that comparing subclasses would really use the superclass `Comparable` interface). Is this LSP adhered to throughout the whole Java package hierarchy, or are there some exceptions?

Comment: @propaganda Comparables, though very useful, are nothing special in as far as the language is concerned -- they're an interface like any other, and the usual rules apply as far as dynamic resolution. So if you call `o.compareTo(...)`, and `o` is of a subclass where the superclass also implements `compareTo`, the subclass version will be called. If you want to compare types of the subclass (e.g., a bunch of ColorSquares) you're better off writing a custom `Comparator`. As for LSP in the JDK classes, I can't think of any times that it's violated, but it's possible.

Comment: I guess Java is more consistent than I first thought! (In my situation I do indeed need the superclass compareTo, so no need to specialize the comparison.), again thanks

Comment: The documentation only discusses transitivity in the case of `x > y && y > z`. Surprisingly, it doesn't cover a case where `x = y && y > z`. I wonder if that's an oversight.

Comment: @shmosel It's actually explicitly _not_ required: "It is strongly recommended, but _not_ strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))" (emphasis in original). BigDecimal is an example of a JDK class that does not follow the recommendation; equality cares about scale (so 2.0 != 2.00) but its compareTo doesn't.

Comment: @yshavit, I wasn't referring to the consistent-with-equals recommendation. I was taking issue with your transitivity example. By `x = y` I meant `x.compareTo(y) == 0`. Not that I disagree with your point. The question actually occurred to me as I was leaving a [similar comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045473/implement-compareto-correctly/36045686#comment59740788_36045686) on another question.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, I misunderstood. In that case, I think the sgn stuff in the docs address that through its implications with the other requirements. I'm at work right now, so don't have time to validate that :)

Answer (score 3):

By default, if you haven't overriden `compareTo`, the implementation from it's superclass will be used.

---

Now come to *best practice*, and open up `Effective Java`<sup>TM</sup>

The basic contract of `compareTo` (and same goes for `equals` method) are:

1. [Reflexivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation): `x.compareTo(x)` should always be 0,
2. Symmetry: `x.compareTo(y)` and `y.compareTo(x)` should always return opposite sign or 0,
3. Transitivity: if `x.compareTo(y) > 0` and `y.compareTo(z) > 0`; then `x.compareTo(z) > 0`

And

> ...there is no way to extend an instantiable class with a new value component while preserving the compareTo contract, unless you are willing to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction

**Update** (thanks to [yshavit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928656/sorting-a-subclass-in-java/11928712#comment15887234_11928712))

<strike>So, you must know what you're dealing with. Ideally, I'd write a `compareTo` in subclass as well, it may or may not use superClass's `compareTo`.</strike> (sorry for the confusion that I have created)

Implementing `compareTo` or `equals` in your subclass, you will be breaking either *symmetry* or *transitivity*. Refer Item: 7, Effective Java<sup>TM</sup>. It suggests that there is no way to extend a class and override the `equals` method (which has same contract as `compareTo`) to it something differently:

> There is simply no way to extend an instantiable class and add an aspect while preserving the equals contract. There is, however, a fine workaround. Follow the advice of Item 14,
>   “Favor composition over inheritance.” Instead of having ColorPoint extend Point,
>   give ColorPoint a private Point field and a public view method (Item 4)

Comment: Dont you mean superclass, not subclass?

Comment: @user439407 ah, I was in hurry... just went to look into Effective Java. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What would the `compareTo` in the subclass do? It would only be able to treat the other object as that of the superclass, or it'll break transitivity. It can only use `this.*` fields and methods available to the superclass, for the same reason. So, how would its implementation differ from that of the super class?

Answer (score 0):

It should, unless your `compareTo` is overridden or if calls some method that is overridden. A better question would show what happened when you tried, and what your concern is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior would be same as you are not overriding the compareTo method, but then make sure your subclass does not alter any attributes in a way that can break break the code in compareTo() method implemented in super class