# Implement CompareTo Correctly

Tags: java, subclass, compareto

I've got the following class:

```
//GetHasCode, toString, and equalsTo removed to keep the question simple.
private String weaponName;
private String weaponType;
private int weaponDamage;

public WeaponObject(String name, String type, int damage)
{
    this.weaponName = name;
    this.weaponType = type;
    this.weaponDamage = damage;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(WeaponObject compare) {

int name = this.getWeaponName().compareTo(compare.getWeaponName());
int type = this.getWeaponType().compareTo(compare.getWeaponType());
int damage = Integer.compare(this.weaponDamage, compare.getWeaponDamage());

  if(name !=0 )
  {
    return name;
  }
  if(type != 0)
  {
      return type;
  }
  if(damage != 0)
  {
     return damage;
  }
  return 0;
```

}

SubClass:

```
public class Sword extends WeaponObject {


    private String swordAttahment;

    public Sword(String name, String type, int damage, String attachment) {
        super(name, type, damage);
        this.swordAttahment = attachment;
    }


    public String getSwordAttahment() {
        return swordAttahment;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo (WeaponObject compare)
    {
        int superCompare = super.compareTo(compare);

        if(superCompare != 0)
        {
            return superCompare;
        }

        Sword other = (Sword)compare;

        int attach = this.getSwordAttahment().compareTo(other.getSwordAttahment());

        if(attach != 0)
        {
            return attach;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. Given that I have a Sword `class` that `extends` WeaponObject, have I correctly implemented my `compareTo` in the Sword class?
2. If the above isn't correct, then how would I correctly implement the `compareTo` method in my subclass?

Comment: `Sword.compareTo()` will throw a `ClassCastException` if you try comparing to a `WeaponObject`.

Comment: @shmosel - How do I fix it?

Comment: WeaponObject doesn't have `getSwordAttahment()` method. So you can not make a comparison based on `swordAttahment`.

Comment: @Svetlana checking `instanceof` is the obvious fix, but there are deeper problems here that are much harder to solve, as per my comment on @rdonuk's answer. My suggestion would be to think hard about whether `Weapon` and `Sword` both need to implement `Comparable` and override `compareTo()`, or if there's another setup that'll work for you. On a side note, `WeaponObject` is no more descriptive a class name than `Weapon`.

Comment: See the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928656/sorting-a-subclass-in-java) for more info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WeaponObject doesn't have `getSwordAttahment()` method. So you can not make a comparison based on `swordAttahment`. You can use `instanceof` to avoid `ClassCastException`

```
@Override
public int compareTo (WeaponObject compare)
{
    int superCompare = super.compareTo(compare);

    if(superCompare != 0)
    {
        return superCompare;
    }

    if(compare instanceof Sword) {
        Sword other = (Sword)compare;

        int attach = this.getSwordAttahment().compareTo(other.getSwordAttahment());

        if(attach != 0)
        {
            return attach;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One more question, could I do this.getClass != compare.getClass() return -1? Instead of instanceof?

Comment: It is your desicion. If you are thinking that "if the class types are different they must be different" you can write that.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and code. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Svetlana, definitely not. You would be breaking symmetry, because `w.compareTo(s) == 0` while `s.compareTo(w) == -1`. Returning 0 would be a better option, but even that could be breaking transitivity, because you can have a scenario where `w.compareTo(s1) == 0 && w.compareTo(s2) == 0 && s1.compareTo(s2) != 0`. You'll also have trouble if you extend `Sword` without overriding `compareTo()`. Either way you'll want to make sure `equals()` implements the same logic, as recommended by the documentation.

Comment: @shmosel - Many thanks for your advice. For the small text adventure game I'm building I don't think compareTo will be implemented.